# Why does the js function need to be inside the html file and cannot be separates in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I currently have something like this

filename : notes.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}



<script src="{% static "bootstrap/js/Notes.js"%}"></script>


 <div class="pure-container" data-effect="pure-effect-slide"  style="height: 10px">
          <label class="pure-toggle-label" for="pure-toggle-left" data-toggle-label="left" style="margin-top:50px">
              <span class="pure-toggle-icon"></span>
          </label>

 </div>
```

Now I have a file called `Notes.js` which is like this (This file is being referenced in Notes.html file.)

Filename : Notes.js

```
$(".pure-toggle-label").click(function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
})
```

Now from the above code when I click on `pure-toggle-label` I expect the console to get "Hello World". However seems like the click function never gets called. Now if I move the content of `Notes.js` to `Notes.html`  surrounded by the tag `<script> </script>` then the function gets called. My question is why this is happening ? Why cant I separately place that function in a separate file and reference that file.Why does the function not get called when the function is moved to a separate js file

Comment: did you added any jquery library before your js file. I didn't see any .  Check browser console for errors

Comment: It sounds like you're attaching the `click` event listener before the DOM exists or is loaded. Try moving the position of your `<script>` tag (after the elements), or wrap the JS in a [DOM ready event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) (i.e., `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: @Anant no browser errors reported

Comment: @JoshCrozier i will give that a try

Comment: @JoshCrozier you were correct looks like the jquery selector was being called before the css was being created. Can you put that as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things need to be taken care:-

1.Add a jquery library before any jQquery code  (otherwise jQuery code will not executed).

2.Either put your script code at the end of the page or change it like below :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".pure-toggle-label").click(function () {
       console.log("Hello World");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Js code (and jquery in your case ) will be executed as soon as the js interpreter find the snippets to execute... if the code to be executed is invoked before any js lib is loaded then you will get an "... not found error"... on the other hand most of initializing functions are anchored to the onload method in the site, this is because most jquery functions are related with dom elements that must be properly loaded before getting manipulated